# How can I store an int array into a number array?

Tags: java

Integer extends Number so in that sense Number becomes the superclass of int. I want to store an int array into a Number array..
I have the following code.However, it seems it is not allowed in java.

```
    int[] b = {1,2};
    Number[] a = b;
```

Why java does not allow me to store an int array in number array and how do I store this out ?

Comment: beware  Integer is the object, and int are a primitive type.

Comment: To do that make the int array into an Integer array: `Integer[] b = {1,2};` then you can `Number[] a = b;`

Comment: "Integer extends Number " but int does not :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that directly, because an "array-of-primitives" is not an "array-of-objects". Autoboxing does not occur with arrays.

But you can use [`ArrayUtils.toObject(b)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28int%5B%5D%29) (from commons-lang). This will create a new array of the wrapper type (`Integer`) and fill it with the values from the primitive array:

```
int[] a = {1,2};
Number[] n = ArrayUtils.toObject(a);
```

Answer (score 5):

Because int and Integer are two separate types. The first one is a primitive type, and the second one is an object type. Integer extends Number, but int is not even a class, and it thus can't extend anything.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess this has something to do with `Number` being an abstract class ([API Page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)), meaning the it cannot be used to represent an item, but allows other classes to share functionality. If you could store items in a `Number` array, they would lose their type, and become instances of `Number`, which is impossible as it's abstract.

Comment: An object never loses its type. If you store an Integer inside an array of Numbers, it stays an Integer. It's just referenced, in the array, as a Number. And it's alright, since an Integer *is* a Number. If I put you in a queue of travellers, to me, you're just a traveller. But that doesn't mean you lose your identity of ianhales.

Comment: Fair enough, my Java is rusty to say the least! This is what I get for working in Matlab these days ;)